# Worklight server exception

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

WL 5.0.6

A client is authenticated to a number of Realms. Make a call to an adapter procedures. The procedures's security test seem to work, we see access where it should be and deniel where it should be. But each attempted call shows this error in the server logs.

It seem likely this is just noise, but can anyone confirm this? Better still can we stop it? Or is there something we must fix?

[6/25/13 22:54:51:846 EDT] 00000061 SystemOut                                                    O [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication():556'
    [6/25/13 22:54:51:847 EDT] 00000061 SystemOut                                                    O com.worklight.server.auth.impl.WorkLightAuthenticationException
    [6/25/13 22:54:51:847 EDT] 00000061 SystemOut                                                    O   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:556)
    [6/25/13 22:54:51:847 EDT] 00000061 SystemOut                                                    O   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.login(AuthenticationContext.java:644)
    [6/25/13 22:54:51:847 EDT] 00000061 SystemOut                                                    O   at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.login(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:118)
    [6/25/13 22:54:51:847 EDT] 00000061 SystemOut                                                    O   at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.LoginOnDemandHandler.doPost(LoginOnDemandHandler.java:69)
    [6/25/13 22:54:51:847 EDT] 00000061 SystemOut                                                    O   at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:125)

Comment: Is there any details of what exception is thrown? Generally directly above the top log post you made in the logs?

Comment: I thought I'd grabbed everything relevant. I will check, but I think that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM74090

What version of Liberty/WAS are you using?

Can you set the custom property **com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressLoggingServiceRuntimeExcep = true** and try again.